# Cutting Sheets on Unique Values in each column

Tags: python, pandas

On a quarterly basis I have to cut a master file that is sent to me from the hire ups based on a few specified columns which are Region, City, and Department. I wrote a script that does the cutting for me but unfortunately I cant figure out a way how to run only 1 iteration of same script versus same scripts changed for each column

```py
Input = pd.read_excel('Master.xlsx', header = 0)

for d in Input['Region'].unique():
    temp_df = Input[Input['Region']==d]
    temp_df.drop(temp_df.columns[32:37], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    temp_df.to_excel('Quarterly_Cut_for_{}'.format(d), index = False)

for d in Input['City'].unique():
    temp_df = Input[Input['City']==d]
    temp_df.drop(temp_df.columns[32:37], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    temp_df.to_excel('Quarterly_Cut_for_{}'.format(d), index = False)

for d in Input['Dept'].unique():
    temp_df = Input[Input['Dept']==d]
    temp_df.drop(temp_df.columns[32:37], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    temp_df.to_excel('Quarterly_Cut_for_{}'.format(d), index = False)
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to run the script for all 3 columns above in one script versus having 1 for each column

Comment: Are you trying to get one file per unique combination of Region City Department?

Comment: @ Andrew Lavers actually now I am trying to get a file just for each unique value in column, no combination needed. Its just the way the file is built and its literally filtered for each region and making a new file, then resetting filter and doing it by dept, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This produces a dataframe for each unique combination of three attributes. Replace `print(sub_df)` with the operations you need (select columns, write to csv)

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""Region,City,Department,value
R1,C1,D1,1
R1,C1,D2,2
R1,C2,D3,3
R1,C2,D3,4
R2,C3,D5,5
R2,C3,D5,6
R2,C3,D6,7
"""))

grouper = df.groupby(["Region","City", "Department"])

for g in grouper:
    sub_df = pd.DataFrame(g[1]).reset_index(drop=True)
    print(sub_df)

#    Region City Department  value
# 0      R1   C1         D1      1
#    Region City Department  value
# 0      R1   C1         D2      2
#    Region City Department  value
# 0      R1   C2         D3      3
# 1      R1   C2         D3      4
#    Region City Department  value
# 0      R2   C3         D5      5
# 1      R2   C3         D5      6
#    Region City Department  value
# 0      R2   C3         D6      7
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I actually don't want to group the columns, I need to just write a file for each unique category in each column, not combinations of them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```py
Columns = ['Region', 'City', 'Dept']


for c in columns:
    for d in Input[c].unique():
    temp_df = Input[Input[c]==d]
    temp_df.drop(temp_df.columns[32:37], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    temp_df.to_excel('Quarterly_Cut_for_{}'.format(d), index = False)
```